# How can I invoke UART_Receive_IT() automatically when I receive a data?

Tags: stm32, uart, freertos

I am new to STM32 and freertos. I need to write a program to send and receive data from a module via UART port. I have to send(Transmit) a data to that module(for eg. M66). Then I would return to do some other tasks. once the M66 send a response to that, my seial-port-receive-function(HAL_UART_Receive_IT) has to be invoked and receive that response. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

The way `HAL_UART_Receive_IT` works is that you configure it to receive specified amount of data into given buffer. You give it your buffer to which it'll read received data and number of bytes you want to receive. It then starts receiving data. Once exactly this amount of data is received, a callback function `HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback` gets called (from IRQ) where you can do whatever you want with this data, e.g. add it to some kind of queue for later processing in the task context.

If I was to express my experiences related to working with HAL's UART module is that it's not the greatest one for generic use where you don't know the amount of data you expect to receive in advance. In the case of M66 modem you mention, this will happen all the time.

To solve this you have two choices:

1. Simply don't use HAL functions at all in case of UART, other than the initialization functions. Implement your own UART interrupt handler (most of the code can be copied from handler in HAL) where upon receiving data you place received bytes in a receive byte queue handled in your RTOS task. In this task you implement protocol parsing. This is the approach I use personally.
2. If you really want to use HAL but also work with a module that sends varying amount of data, call `HAL_UART_Receive_IT` and specify that you want to receive 1 byte each time. This will work, but will be (potentially much) slower than the first approach. Assuming you'll later want to implement some tcp/ip communication (you mentioned M66 GPRS module) you probably don't want to do it this way.

Comment: Thanks @Jacek...How can I Implement my own UART interrupt handler?...can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: HAL implementation can be found inside `void HAL_UART_IRQHandler(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)`. You call this function from ISR, specifying a pointer to `UART_HandleTypeDef` you're handling. In your case - implementing your own interrupt handler - it'd probably be the best approach to copy the contents of the function mentioned and substituting HAL function calls to your own functions. All restrictions and guidelines when it comes to implementing interrupt handlers apply, such as keeping them as short as possible. Doing some research on your own will probably be helpful also.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the following way.

Enable UARTX Rx interrupt in NVIC.
Set Interrupt priority.
Unmask Interrupt request in EXTI.

Then use USARTX Interrupt Handler Function Define in you Vector.

Whenever the data is received from USARTX this function get automatically called and you can copy data from USARTX Receive Data Register.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather suggest another approach. You probably want to archive higher speeds (lets say 921600 bods) and the interrupt way is fat to slow for it.

You need to implement the DMA transmition with the data end detection features. Run your USART in the DMA mode in the circular mode. You will have two events to serve. The first one is the DMA end of thransmition interrupt (then you copy the data from the current tail pointer to the end of the buffer to avoid data override) and USART IDLE interrupt - this will detect the end of the receive.